# How to force apt-get to install automake v1.16 while it says 1.15 is already the newest version?

Tags: software-installation, automake

I got an error of `missing aclocal-1.16 -I m4` in building my system. I tried to fix it by installing the newest version of `automake`, but it tells me that my `automake` is **1.15** which is already the newest version.

I googled it and found the newest version 1.16 of `automake` is available at "https://git.adelielinux.org/adelie/packages/-/tree/current/system/automake", so it's obvious that my 'automake' is not the newest one and that blocks me from finishing my build for my 'aclocal' is 1.15.

How can I force apt-get to get the newest version of 'automake' from the above link?

Comment: This is not how Ubuntu packages work...

Comment: The package rules ensure your system remains *stable* and doesn't crash due to ABI/API breakage & thus *segfaults* or *kernel panics* (if kernel related). Are you trying to break the *stability* and make a *frakensystem*?  Did you verify that no API changed during those versions?  If you want later software, it's best to compile the newer versions so they'll run on your system (*by doing the compiling, you're ensuring the API's all align & won't segfault etc*), OR use other package formats such as *snap*, *flatpak*, *appimage* etc (where everything gets included & you don't have breakage)

Comment: The reason why I'd like to install v1.16 of automake is because I just joined a project team and the lastest version I downloaded to build stopped build, saying which version it needs is 1.16. But when I tried install the newest one version by 'apt-get install automake', it showes the newest one 1.15 is already at my files.

Comment: Automake 1.15 suggests that you are using Ubuntu 16.04 (past End of Standard Support) or Ubuntu 18.04 (End of Standard Support coming in three months!) Consider simply migrating to a newer release of Ubuntu. Automake 1.16 is in the Ubuntu repositories, automatically compatible with Ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu 22.04, Ubuntu 22.10, and the pre-release Ubuntu 23.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

automake looks like it's directly installable in your Ubuntu without needing to install any additional dependencies or making your system unstable by changing its software sources. To install the automake package from the Ubuntu 20.04 default repositories (version 1.16) in your Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/a/automake-1.16/automake_1.16.1-4ubuntu6_all.deb
sudo apt install ./automake_1.16.1-4ubuntu6_all.deb
```

Installing automake 1.16 installs `/usr/bin/aclocal-1.16` and `/usr/share/aclocal-1.16/make.m4` among other files.